# GET request while access token is changing

Tags: python, get, google-chrome-devtools, access-token

I wrote a python script which sends GET requests to some particular website.
In order to perform this request, I need to attach the access token that I was given when I logged in. 
The problem is that the access token is changing each 15 min, and I have to find it over and over again by using Chrome Devtool (Network tab). I was wondering if there is any way to obtain the new token automatically, or any other way to perform this GET request without using this access token but only the credentials (Username and Password) for this website.
Right now, this is how I'm doing this (Notice that the data provided is not real, so please don't try to use) :

```
url = "https://www.containers.io/web/alerts"

querystring = {"access_token":"cfc6f6d22f00303fb7ac--f","envId":"58739be2c2","folderId":"active","sortBy":"status"}

headers = {
    'origin': "https://www.containers.io",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
    'accept': "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    'referer': "https://www.containers.io",
    'connection': "keep-alive",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

JSON_format = response.json()
```

Comment: They're trying to prevent you from doing things like this. You should not try to get around it.

Comment: That said, anything the browser can do, you can do in Python. Use DevTools to see how the browser gets the updated token, then code that in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice an handshake implementation of this. Pass the access-code with your request and make sure the response returned contains that same access-code which you can then use to generate another code to make a second or more requests. Hope this answers your question